# Получение конкретного значения поля JSON

Tags: c#, json

Получаю JSON от API [нац банка РБ](https://www.nbrb.by/) в таком виде:

```json
{
    Cur_ID: 145,
    Date: "2021-01-04T00:00:00",
    Cur_Abbreviation: "USD",
    Cur_Scale: 1,
    Cur_Name: "Доллар США",
    Cur_OfficialRate: 2.5789
}
```

Есть ли возможность сформировать запрос таким образом (с помощью заголовков, или еще чего-то) что бы получать только значение поля `Cur_OfficialRate`, при этом не создавая отдельной модели в которую будут парситься все поля объекта? То есть, я отсылаю запрос и мне приходит только значение `2.5789`.

Это нужно для того что бы создать универсальный метод, который будет работать с различными API и возвращать мне только значение нужного мне поля (т.к JSON от разных банков будут отличаться).

Comment: `Есть ли возможность сформировать запрос таким образом` - почему этот вопрос адресован нам, а не банку и его API?

Comment: Нет. не можете. Вы запросом не можете влиять на формат ответа не оговоренного документацией если конечно она есть

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да вот как тут помочь даже и не знаю :)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вопрос был в том, реально ли вообще достать только то, что нужно

Comment: Если сервер это не поддерживает, то нет, вам надо так или иначе вытянуть сначала все то, что дает сервер, разобрать это (десериализовать), а уж затем вытягивать то, что вам надо. И тут я думаю вы уже сами понимаете, что мы без понятия, имеет такую возможность сервер или нет. Не бывает универсальных решений, ибо нету стандартов и один сайт может вам выдать данные, где будет значение `МоеКлевоеЗначение1`, а другой может выдать `SCV` и вот как вы будете искать из этих данных нужное? Как вы сделаете универсальный алгоритм, который определит, что `SCV` это именно нужное значение в файле? А не как..

Comment: Делайте абстракцию, делайте интерфейс, например `IBankData` и в нем метод, который будет возвращать вам нужное значение, ну а дальше делайте классы, где в классе `Bank1` вы реализуете получение данных из JSON что в ответе, а в классе `Bank2` уже реализуйте другую логику, где такое значение будете получать другими способами, теми, что подходят для того банка. И вот у вас уже будет решение, которое хотяб можно будет масштабировать и легко поддерживать, но универсальное... Не думаю...

Comment: Если не хотите создавать классы-модели, то используйте [JsonDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=net-5.0) (или аналогичный класс из той библиотеки, которую вы используете для работы с json). И из него берите нужное значение.

Comment: Вам по сути не нужен весь класс, описывающий JSON-ответ, достаточно простого `class Data { public double? Cur_OfficialRate { get; set; } }`. Остальные поля JSON будут проигнорированы, если вы правильно сконфигурируете JSON-парсер.

Comment: `создать универсальный метод, который будет работать с различными API и возвращать мне только значение нужного мне поля` если разные банки отдают ответы в разных форматах, то сделать то что вы хотите в принципе невозможно.

Comment: @VladD тут автор хочет совсем просто - десериализацию сразу в `double` по имени свойства

Comment: @Andrei Khotko: Понимаю, вы правы. Но мне кажется, пусть использует паттерн «Адаптер», а что там под капотом и какой именно JSON приходит, должно быть неважно.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Тут автору пофиг вообще на JSON, он хочет, чтоб сервер ему сразу дал нужное значение и спрашивает **как**. И нужно ему это для того, чтоб с различных источников он мог получать данные неким "универсальным" способом. Только вот он походу не понимает, что все сервера работают по-разному и отдают разные вид данных и сделать универсальный метод, который возьмет из полученных данных только то, что он хочет, в принципе невозможно.